# How to automatically set 2D-plot y- and x -axis limits equal in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm plotting a 2D scatter plot in Matlab and I would like to have the ylim and xlim have the same lower and upper bound. Is there a command to do this automatically without that I would have to manually check which axis has bigger maximum value and which one the lower minimum value in order to set the limits manually using `xlim` and `ylim`?

Thnx for any help =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
>> axis equal
```

to set the aspect ratio of x-y to be the same

For a manual setting

```
>> v = axis; % get current values
>> lo = min( v(1:2:end) ); % lower limit
>> up = max( v(2:2:end) ); % uppper limit
>> axis( [lo up lo up] );
```

Comment: The question is different, it asks to set both lower limits of the axis to the min among xy and the upper limits to the max among xy.

Comment: @Shai Thank you for your help, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for as Oleg noted :)

Comment: @jjepsuomi edited my solution, hope this better suits your needs now.,